# Is there any reason to create a local $(this) variable in a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Do I save any memory or performance if I do this

```
function foo(){
   var $this = $(this);
   var class = $this.class();
   var attr = $this.attr();
}
```

Over this

```
function foo(){
   var class = $(this).class();
   var attr = $(this).attr();
}
```

Comment: You can use it for performance reason, executing a function take time.

Comment: Every time you call `$(this)` you're making an extra function call and allocating more memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The performance difference may be minimal for simple applications, but it exists.  Consider that `$()` is a function, so any time you invoke that function the engine has to execute the code within that function.  Referencing an existing variable is going to be a lot faster than executing that potentially large function.

To put it another way, this:

```
var x = someFunction();
someOtherFunction(x);
```

will always be faster than this:

```
someFunction();
someOtherFunction(someFunction());
```